# How do I list the next 7 days and any events (cpt) contained in those days

Tags: custom-post-types, events

I need to list the next seven days no matter what day it is.  If its monday, it starts with today and lists 7 days, if its friday it starts with today and lists 7 days from today.

Next I need to show any events for that day.  IF there are no events for a given day it simply lists a default graphic.

I am going to make a featured event for a each day and eventually set it up so that it just shows that one but for now I just want to list the next 7 days and any events contained within them.

I have two piece that don't fit together very well.  First:

```
<?php $cur_day = 'current_day'; $last = 'last';
$date = date('o-m-d'); $ts = strtotime($date); $dow = date('w', $ts); 
for ($i=0; $i<7; $i++, $ts+=86400){ ?>
```

This will list each of the next 7 days starting with today.

```
 $event_query = new WP_Query(
        array( 
          'post_type'   => 'event',        // only query events
          'meta_key'    => 'event-date',  // load up the event_date meta
          'orderby'     => 'meta_value',
          'order'       => 'asc',         // ascending, so earlier events first
          'meta_query'  => array(
             array(         // restrict posts based on meta values
              'key'     => 'event-date',  // which meta to query
              'value'   => $event_date,  // value for comparison
              'compare' => '=',          // method of comparison
              'type'    => 'NUMERIC'         // datatype, we don't want to compare the string values
            ) // meta_query is an array of query ites
           ) // end meta_query array
          ) // end array
        ); // close WP_Query constructor call
```

This lists the next seven days but doesn't do well with the events...

I am looking to duplicate this: http://www3.dmagazine.com/events with cpt's

thanks   PLEASE HELP

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should definitely do it in just a single query. then set up a simple loop, each iteration get that day's date. then loop through all posts and compare the date to the date meta field, and output if it matches. I think something like this should work...

```
$today = date("o-m-d");
$future = strtotime ( '+6 days' , strtotime ( $today ) ) ;
$future = date ( 'o-m-d' , $future );
$event_query = new WP_Query(
    array( 
      'post_type'   => 'event',
      'meta_key'    => 'event-date',
      'orderby'     => 'meta_value',
      'order'       => 'asc',
      'meta_query'  => array(
         array(
          'key'     => 'event-date',
          'value'   => array($today,$future),
          'compare' => 'BETWEEN',
          'type'    => 'DATE'
        )
       )
      ) 
    );

for ($i=0; $i<7; $i++){
    $thedate = strtotime ( '+'.$i.' day' , strtotime ( $today ) ) ;
    $thedate = date ( 'o-m-d' , $thedate );
    echo $thedate;
    // loop thru all posts and check $thedate against your date meta
    // and output if it matches
    // then rewind_posts(); to set it up for the next day
}
```

Comment: So the initial QP_Query is getting all the events that fit between today and the 7 days from now.  Then if I hear you right, I need to run a simple query_posts loop inside of the for loop that is currently echoing the dates and compare $thedate to event-date.  IS that what you have in mind?